# How do I see the value of a GUID in the Visual Studio 2008 debugger?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

When you look at a GUID values item in the watch window you do not see the value of the item, when you expand the item you just see “**Empty**” this is **very** misleading!

You have to add “ToString()” to the value to see something useful.

So how do I get Visual Studio to add the “ToString()” it’s self?

---

I am using VB.NET if it make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: [Visualizing GUIDs in the Visual Studio 2008 debugger](http://www.michelrenaud.com/?p=7)

---

Edit by Ian

Thanks that worked well, however I had to change

```
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString}", Target:=GetType(Guid))>
```

to

```
<Assembly: DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}", Target:=GetType(Guid))>
```

so it also worked from C#

Answer (score 3):

When i add a guid to the watch window, it shows its value without having to expand it (the ToString() is automatically used).

How are you creating your guid? If you are using

```
Guid x = new Guid();
```

then yes, it will be an "empty" guid.
If you use

```
Guid x = Guid.NewGuid();
```

then you will see that it has a value.

Comment: yeah, same here. Not sure if Ian is programming in VB.NET - in C# for sure, I do see the contents of a GUID property or field just fine in the Debug watch window

Comment: I was wondering the same a while ago. Why my guids were all zeros, hehe. `Guid.NewGuid()` is the correct way to get a new Guid :)

Comment: That explains why I did not remember it as a problem; I have just started a new job when most of the code is in VB.NET rather than C#